# Create a function in Google Sheets with these conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using two different sheets, one for the values I'm going to need and one for counting the values of the first Sheet based on a number of conditions.

[Sheet 1]
[image: 1]

[Sheet 2]
[image: 2]

I'm using this formula to Count the values:

```
=(COUNTIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A;"*m003*";'Sheet 1'!A:A;"*m001*";'Sheet 1'!A:A;"*P165*";'Sheet 1'!B:B;1))/(COUNTIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A;"*m001*";'Sheet 1'!A:A;"*P165*"))
```

With this context, I'd like know if it'd be possible to create a function, macro or something that would let me do this operation by inputting some cells with the information I'd need instead of having to write "m003", "m001", "p165" or another value every time I want to execute the formula mentioned with any variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace them with cells:

```
=(COUNTIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A;"*"&A1&"*";'Sheet 1'!A:A;"*"&C1&"*";'Sheet 1'!A:A;"*"&D1&"*";'Sheet 1'!B:B;1))/(COUNTIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A;"*"&C1&"*";'Sheet 1'!A:A;"*"&D1&"*"))
```

where,

A1: m003
C1: m001
D1: P165

Comment: @Foxinetra Rather than commenting to say "thanks," you should show your appreciation by clicking the check mark to the left of this answer to mark it as "accepted." Doing so awards 15 reputation points to the author and visually shows others that the answer solved your problem. You can also click the up arrow there to vote the answer up. Doing so awards an additional 10 reputation points to the author and increments the score of the answer. The top scored answer is sorted to the top which helps other people with similar problems find it.